# Java Custom Properties File Read integer values in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Hi I have my own `properties` file, but when I want to get `order` value that time it returns `0`, how can I read integer value in custom spring properties class

```java
@Component 
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties 
public class MyProperties {

    private Integer order;
```

`my.properties` file like that

```
enableAll=true
order=1
myvalue=ABC
```

Comment: can you also post your properties file

Comment: Where is `my.properties` located?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing getters and setters.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyProperties {
    private boolean enableAll;
    private Integer order;
    private String myvalue;


    public boolean isEnableAll() {
        return enableAll;
    }

    public void setEnableAll(boolean enableAll) {
        this.enableAll = enableAll;
    }

    public Integer getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Integer order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public String getMyvalue() {
        return myvalue;
    }

    public void setMyvalue(String myvalue) {
        this.myvalue = myvalue;
    }
}
```

With this setup the following test runs successfully

```
import com.example.demo.gq.MyProperties;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyPropertiesTests {

    @Autowired
    MyProperties myProperties;

    @Test
    public void myProps() {
        assertThat(myProperties.getOrder()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(myProperties.isEnableAll()).isTrue();
        assertThat(myProperties.getMyvalue()).isEqualTo("ABC");
    }

}
```